# About YouTube API data storing

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

YouTube API Terms of Service: [Developer Policy III.E.4.b.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#e.-handling-youtube-data-and-content) states:

> Note that even though an API Client may store this data for more than 30 days, the Client must still ensure every 30 days that it is still authorized by the user to access that data.

What does "ensure" mean?

Do we need to have a terrible UX that makes users re-authenticate every 30 days? Or do we just need to verify that the OAuth 2.0 credentials are valid?

Comment: You need to use the Oath token and retrieve a refresh token every so often ..  Refresh tokens have a much shorter lifespan ..  But when you refresh, it extends the Oath token expiry.  Most likely in this case .. 30 days.

Comment: Mind adding a Link to where you found that in the docs?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I have added the documentation link. What do you think about the comments I made on your answer? Please reply!

Comment: @koyamat I think you are all good don't worry.  Just remember to clean out the data if you loose authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every 30 days use your refresh token to get a new access token if it works log the date to show you have access if it doesn't work then delete the data you have stored or..

What I normally do is contact the owner and ask them to authorize the app again wait a week if they haven't then delete the data.

You could check every twenty days if you want to stay on the good side of the 30day limit.

> 1. use a refresh token every day to get a new access token

This is what they are designed to do

> 2. use it to retrieve the day's data. 2. use it to retrieve the day's data and store it in our database.

This is what the api is designed to do

> 3. one day, if it is revoked, delete the stored data.

This is what the we are directed to do by YouTube.

Sounds like your design is all within the guidelines as written. Note I am not a lawyer or a employee of YouTube, I am merely a developer like you interpreting the guidelines as written.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison  
Thank you for the comment. I would like to implement the following specification, is this problematic?  
  
On the backend side, we will use a refresh token to obtain a new access token every 30 days, and if it cannot be obtained at that time (=revoked), it will be detected and the stored data will be deleted.

Comment: You meant [@Linda Lawton DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/linda-lawton-daimto).

Comment: No, I meant you, @BenjaminLoison.  
And I referred to our product's specification. Sorry for being so confusing.  
  
In our product, we would like to get data from youtube api every day, store it, and display daily data trends.
  
If we could work this way, would it be a violation of youtube's policy?  
1. use a refresh token every day to get a new access token 2. use it to retrieve the day's data.  
2. use it to retrieve the day's data and store it in our database.   
3. one day, if it is revoked, delete the stored data.

Comment: @koyamat I just edited the answer to correct the typos, I don't have any opinion concerning your question/the answer I corrected.

Comment: Sorry, I understood!! @Linda Lawton DalmTo how about my comment?